# Validating multiple xml files with Saxon fails if substitutionGroup members are added to the schema after the first file is validated

Tags: java, xml, xsd, saxon, xsd-validation

I am encountering difficulties when trying to validate multiple XML files against multiple schema documents using Saxon.  The difficulties are caused by the substitutionGroup relationships that exist between several elements.  Here is a simple reconstruction of the problem.

The schemas are:

family.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://myexample/family" xmlns:fam="http://myexample/family" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <element name="FamilyMember" type="string" />
  <element name="Parent" type="string" substitutionGroup="fam:FamilyMember"/>
  <element name="Child" type="string" substitutionGroup="fam:FamilyMember"/>
  <element name="Family">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element ref="fam:FamilyMember" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>  
</schema>
```

family_ext.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://myexample/family_ext" xmlns:fam="http://myexample/family" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <import namespace="http://myexample/family" schemaLocation="http://www.valid.nl/taxo3/family.xsd"/>
  <element name="Cousin" type="string" substitutionGroup="fam:FamilyMember"/>
</schema>
```

The two instance documents are:

family1.xml

```
<Family xmlns="http://myexample/family">
  <Parent>John</Parent>
  <Child>Alice</Child>
</Family>
```

family2.xml

```
<Family xmlns="http://myexample/family" xmlns:fam2="http://myexample/family_ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://myexample/family_ext http://www.valid.nl/taxo3/family_ext.xsd" >
  <Parent>John</Parent>
  <Child>Alice</Child>
  <fam2:Cousin>Pete</fam2:Cousin>
</Family>
```

Here is the problem: I first load the family.xsd into the Saxon configuration using the addSchemaSource method.  I then validate family1.xml.  This works.  If I then try to validate family2.xml, I get the following error:

```
In content of element <Family>: The content model does not allow element <Q{.../family_ext}Cousin> to appear immediately after element <{http://myexample/family}Child>. Expected <Q{.../family}FamilyMember> or nothing.
```

However, if I first validate family2.xml, validation succeeds (and if I then validate family1.xml this also succeeds).

A workaround I have found for this problem is to clear the schema cache between validations.  However this is ultimately not a very satisfying solution because in the actual use-case I have a cache with tens of schemas and would rather not have to keep reloading them. Furthermore, when I start the validation I do not yet know what the total collection of shemas will be, so I cannot pre-emptively load them all (in the context of the example above, I cannot load both family.xsd and family_ext.xsd at the start of the validation).

Why is the order in which I am performing the validations important?  And is there a way to get Saxon to handle these kinds of validations without having to keep clearing the schema cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saxon should give you an error when you load the second schema document, saying that you cannot add members to a substitution group that has already been used for validation. The reason for this is that changing the schema invalidates previous results. In an XSLT/XQuery context this is relevant because the first document might still be around, and its type annotations (derived from schema processing) might affect the way it is processed; if the schema types that were used at validation time are materially different from the schema types used at query/transformation time, then all kinds of things can go wrong. So the answer to your question is, in general, you should load all of your schema documents into the Saxon Configuration before using the (assembled) schema. In fact the rules aren't quite as strict as that, there are many changes you can make safely. The changes Saxon checks for and tries to prevent are adding to the membership of a substitition group, and adding new types derived by extension from existing types. There are other unsafe changes too, which Saxon probably ought to check for: for example if you add a new global element declaration named X, then this can invalidate content that contains an element called X if it was laxly validated.

I don't know why Saxon isn't reporting the error when you add to the substitution group. I'll investigate that.

What's actually happening here is that the anonymous complex type used for the Family element is compiled into a finite-state-machine used for the validation process. This FSM takes into account known substitution group members. It looks like the original FSM is being used to validate new elements without taking into account that new substitution group members have been added.

Later: I have tried to reproduce this as follows:

```
            Processor proc = new Processor(true);
            SchemaManager sm = proc.getSchemaManager();
            sm.load(new StreamSource(new StringReader(sch1)));
            System.err.println("Schema 1 OK");
            sm.newSchemaValidator().validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(doc1)));
            System.err.println("Doc 1 OK");
            sm.load(new StreamSource(new StringReader(sch2)));
            System.err.println("Schema 2 OK");
            sm.newSchemaValidator().validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(doc2)));
            System.err.println("Doc 2 OK");
```

where sch1, sch2, doc1, and doc2 are your example documents and schemas. I get what I would expect, on loading sch2:

```
    net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: It is not possible to add to the 
substitution group of element FamilyMember in namespace 'http://myexample/family', 
because the schema for that namespace has already been used for validating instance 
documents, or for compiling queries or stylesheets
```

Comment: We discovered that this behaviour of Saxon is actually documented in the SchemaManager class of the [.NET api](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/SchemaManager.html) (shame this isn't also present in the java doc!). The reason I did not get the exception you expected is because I was not explicitly loading the family_ext schema into the configuration, but instead letting Saxon discover it via the schemaLocation hint.  If I explicitly load the schema I indeed get the exception you mention.

Comment: OK. If you rely on the schema-location hint, it will be ignored on the grounds that a schema for the required namespace is already available. I was under the impression that the MULTIPLE_SCHEMA_IMPORTS option would force it to be loaded anyway, but it appears not.